# Using setTimeout to prevent long running script bugs in IE8 - why does it depend on the interval?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8, settimeout

I'm trying to write some JavaScript to run against IE8. It's to do with sorting a moderately large set of data (actually, for 99% of users its a very small set of data - but as always, there's some edge cases) . I've been investigating ways to execute a long script on IE8 without either blocking the UI or causing the 'Long Running Script' message.

A popular solution is to use window.setTimeout to stagger function calls and then return that variable at the end asynchronously. The common advice is to write a recursive function and call it with

```
window.setTimeout(fn, 1);
```

because this is supposed to add the call to the thread's event queue. UI operations will be interleaved with setTimeout calls and the browser will remain responsive. IE8 won't moan, the idea goes, because its statement counter is reset when the timeout is invoked.

But I have a problem. **I've found that in IE8, the long running script exception only disappears if the timeout is long enough**.

I've written some functions that increment a number to 3 million using staggered function calls that each perform 50,000 n++ operations. These functions perform many operations (actually, massively more than even my worst use case), but none should break IE's documented [5 million instruction limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500). Here's the thing, though: **if I stagger the functions with a 1ms timeout, I get a long running script warning in IE8 half way through (after several function calls). If I stagger them with a 15ms timeout, I don't. How come?** Is this something to do with the granularity of the Win32 timing API?

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yb79vx7h/1/ , and an embedded version you can try for yourself in IE8
: http://jsfiddle.net/yb79vx7h/1/embedded/result/

Edit: curiously, I can replicate the same problems with the 15ms code if I count to 9 million using 600,000 iterations. That prompts the 'Stop running this script?' dialog in IE8 too. So it seems to be to do with the amount of actions versus the timeout length.

Comment: Don't be tricked into thinking that `setTimeout` will spawn a new thread, because it won't. It'll just push the callback function call to the end of the call queue, and call the function after (approx) Xms delay _in the main, and only_ thread. Using a timeout of 1ms probably means you're queue is filled with several consecutive calls to `fn` before anything else, causing IE to complain

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - surely, the 15ms code would then exhibit the same behaviour if I don't interrupt the count by, e.g. clicking or triggering any other UI events? As far as I can tell, it doesn't.

Comment: Not necessarily: If IE8 takes more than 1ms from the point where `setTimeout` is called, then the call stack will contain 2 calls to your function, possibly hitting the instruction limit _and_ clogging up the call stack, effectively blocking the UI (event loop etc...). The 15ms delay might be enough to have the JScript engine idle for a couple of ms, allowing for IE to check the event loop, and proceeding as normal. I'm just guessing here (don't have IE on any of my machines, so can't check).

Comment: It's probably best for you to do some digging, there are some specific [IE 8 debugger tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gpde/archive/2009/08/03/javascript-memory-leak-detector-v2.aspx) that might help you in doing so. Hopefully for you, there is a tool that can tell you to how many instructions your actual code translates internally. The results are often [surprising to say the least](http://amasad.me/2014/01/06/building-an-in-browser-javascript-vm-and-debugger-using-generators/)

Comment: Perhaps consider using a closure, and bind/unbind the event handlers when and where you need them. That'd enable you to keep the event loop light. [I've added an example of this approach to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzgxan76/) (the output uses `console.log`, so use the console to check what it does)

Comment: Oh, and a final thought: you can replicate the problem with the 15ms timeouts because you don't really have any control over what the JS engine does, and when it does it. Because your event handlers are inlined in your HTML, it's very likely you end up with 2 timeout loops running next to each other, add to that your usage of global variables and you're in trouble. It's better to use closures, as I did, if only to avoid you stepping on a global var

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - the thing is, the MS documentation actually says that the warning is triggered by the instruction count, and that gets reset when calling code through setTimeout. Is this documentation then incorrect? Does IE need an *n* millisecond pause between function calls in order to count them separately?

Comment: I don't know what mechanism IE uses internally, but from what you describe here, I wouldn't be surprised to learn that the instruction count is nothing more than a tally of the instructions left to perform, meaning that a `setTimeout` before the return of a function adds _N_ instructions, on top of those left in the function. Couple that to a scenario where the event loop is actually busy, and you _can_ hit the limit quite easily

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - the setTimeout is running at the very end of those functions, though.